# Isomorphism of Abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I want to know whether my approach to solving this sum is correct.

Suppose that $G$ is a finite abelian group of order $3^{4}\times 3^{10}$ and I want to show $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{81}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{10}}$. Suppose I show $G$ has at least one element of order $3^4$ and one element of order $3^{10}$, say $a, b$ respectively, such that $a\not\in \langle b\rangle$ and $b\not\in\langle a\rangle$,
can I then state $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{81}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{10}}$?
All I want to know is if this is the correct approach or not, and if not, what else I need to follow. Please help.

Comment: Doesn't $\mathbb Z_{3^{14}}$ have the correct order?

Comment: The order is just $3^{14}$ , it is very unusual to split the order. Of course you can say $G=H\times K$ and that $H$ has order $3^4$ and $K$ has order $3^{10}$ , but as stated I agree the above comment.

Comment: If $G$ is cyclic, then $\mathbb{Z}_{3^{14}}$ is the answer. But suppsoe $G$ is non-cyclic, what shall we do ?

Comment: If we do not know that it is the direct product of two $3$-groups having the given orders , there are many other possibilities. Even if we know that the first group has order $3^4$ and the second $3^{10}$ , each of the groups could be a direct product of even smaller groups.

Comment: @KentaS I was thinking about this, maybe I am wrong, but if we choose two elements $a, b$ of order $3^4, 3^{10}$ respectively, shouldn't they satisfy at least $a\in \langle b\rangle$ or $b\in \langle a\rangle$ ? Moreover, I am willing to show $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{81}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{10}}$ only.

Comment: @Peter ohho. Ok I realize now. Any specific way then ?

Comment: @Peter Will the condition "$a\not\in \langle b\rangle, b\not\in \langle a\rangle$" be anyhow useful in the above argument ?

Answer (score 2):

counterexample:

$G=\mathbb Z_{3^{13}}\times\mathbb Z_{3}$, now set
$a=(3^3,0),b=(3^{9},1)$ and note that $o(a)=3^{10},o(b)=3^{4}$. Clearly we have that $b\not\in \langle a\rangle$ (has a one in the second component) and $a\not\in \langle b\rangle$ ($o(a)>o(b)$).

Comment: I understood your example. Nice one!